# I pressed some button accidentally and now the loop cut tool is invisible for the selected objects

Tags: interface, loop

So I think I pressed some button and something happened to the objects I had selected. Now on these objects when I go into edit mode and press ctrl-r to add loop cuts the new orange lines don't appear when the tool is active. I can still add loop cuts but the cuts only appear once the tool has finished.  On other objects the loop cut still works ok and I can see where the new loop cuts appear.

They are not ngons, no double vertices, no flipped normals, no weird modifiers...

Comment: Make a backup of the current state to disc.
Try hitting ALT-H once (to unhide anything which got hitten) and CTRL-Z for "Undo" several times

Comment: The first thing I did was to restart blender but I had already saved before I noticed the issue. So undo doesn't save me.

Comment: Are you using 2.79 or 2.8 ? Can you please share the .blend file ?

Comment: 2.8. No I can't share the blend file